# How to combine Autocomplete and filter search on yadcf Datatable?

Tags: autocomplete, datatables, yadcf

I need to combine on input search two filter type : "Autocomplete" and "text".

See this example : http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/ajax_source.html.

I need the fonctionnality of the input of the second Column (Browser) and the column Platform.

It is possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

yadcf is not designed for such scenario, but you try to init yadcf with different filter types (by pressing some dedicated button - but I haven't tested it myself

```
//at start - call this code
yadcf.init(oTable2, [{
    column_number: 0
    filter_type: "text",
}]);


//then, when clicking on "filter toggle button" - call this code
yadcf.init(oTable2, [{
    column_number: 0
    filter_type: "auto_complete",
}]);
```